# SQL LIMIT command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting command not properly ended for the following script, can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Thanks

```
SELECT E_name, E_DOB FROM Empl
ORDER BY E_DOB DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `Oracle`?  How do you run your script?

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `LIMIT`

Comment: `SELECT *
FROM 
(SELECT E_name, E_DOB FROM Empl
ORDER BY E_DOB DESC) 
where ROWNUM <= 3`

Comment: Are you missing that Oracle doesn't have the `LIMIT` keyword, and doesn't support top-N queries natively until [12c's `FETCH` and `OFFSET` additions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1)?

Comment: I was unaware Oracle doesn't support LIMIT. The answer Mihai gave works perfectly thank you all! :)